# Adding check button in dropdown menu/popup menu of tkinter with dynamic input coming in form of list

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-menu

So I am using xlrd module to read names of excel files of a workbook that user selects. Now this comes up in form of a list, which I am able to put in popup menu drop down(able to select on name at a time) now I want to

So far I am able to use the drop down menu of tkinter with dynamic input but able to select just one name at a time, now I want to select multiple items at a time by adding checkbox to the same. Can anyone help.. Here is sample code on which you anyone may please try adding checkbox and select multiple names at a time.

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
a = [] #creates a list to store the job names in
var = StringVar() # creates a stringvar to store the value of options
for i  in range(20): # fills list with nonsense jobs for troubleshooting
    a.append("Job Name "+str(i))
var.set(a[0]) # sets the default option of options
options = OptionMenu(root, var, *a)   
# creates an option menu populated with every element of the list
button = Button(root, text="Ok", command=lambda:print(var.get()))
# prints the current value of options
options.pack()
button.pack()
```

The above code shows a drop down with single select able item, I just want multiple selection functionality enabled by adding checkbox in front of every option

Comment: Above drop down menu code is working properly if not the you may please check indentations

Comment: Need check button added to this drop down

Comment: I don't think you are looking into the right widget for this. Check the [sample here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34549752/how-do-i-enable-multiple-selection-of-values-from-a-combobox) for `Menubutton` instead.

Comment: Hi Henry I was finding solution since long it worked for me... Thanks,...

Answer (score 0):

Use the MenuButton feature in tkinter. It has a method called Menu. To this method you could add as many check buttons as you want. This will support multiselect dropdown option. Give a variable name to each checkbutton and access its state through the get command.

Comment: Thanks Srikanth I already did it using list box, still thanks for taking out time will look forward to help you too.